# Removing "access to drive" permission to run spreadsheet bound app script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

When I share the sheet with a new user the user asked to "give access to his/her drive drive", but I am not using any of the drive functionalities in my code, nor is it included in my services.

what can I do to remove it?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried manually changing the authorization scopes needed to run the script? https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/scopes

Comment: Can you give more context about the functionalities of your code? This is to better understand the whole picture. Also, as far as I know, when you share a Google Spreadsheet file with a script to a user & once he/she runs the script, it is an expected behavior for the user to be asked to give access for the script project to run on the shared Spreadsheet file on the user's end.